# Handle UISlider value in the best way

Tags: swift, uislider

Sorry for this question, and I need an advice here.
I have an slider to change a value in a chart (distance between two points), and I did it in this way, I think this is the worst way to do that, but I can find any better way, could anyone help me to make it in a nicer way, more advance!

Your help will be appreciated

```swift
@objc func stockSliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    let value = sender.value

    stockChart.lineGap = 0.7

    if value == 0 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.5
    } else if value > 0.0, value <= 0.1 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.45
    } else if value > 0.1, value <= 0.15 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.4
    } else if value > 0.15, value <= 0.2 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.35
    } else if value > 0.2, value <= 0.25 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.3
    } else if value > 0.25, value <= 0.3 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.25
    } else if value > 0.3, value <= 0.35 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.2
    } else if value > 0.35, value <= 0.4 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.15
    } else if value > 0.4, value <= 0.45 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.1
    } else if value > 0.45, value <= 5 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap - 0.05
    }

    if value > 0.5, value <= 0.55 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.05
    } else if value > 0.55, value <= 0.6 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.1
    } else if value > 0.6, value <= 0.65 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.15
    } else if value > 0.65, value <= 0.7 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.2
    } else if value > 0.7, value <= 0.75 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.25
    } else if value > 0.75, value <= 0.8 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.3
    } else if value > 0.8, value <= 0.85 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.35
    } else if value > 0.85, value <= 0.9 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.4
    } else if value > 0.9, value <= 0.95 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.45
    } else if value > 0.95, value <= 1 {
        stockChart.lineGap = stockChart.lineGap + 0.5
    }
    stockChart.reDraw()
}
```

Comment: You check `slider.value`, then get a value from it from (the more value is near 0) -0.5 to 0.5 (the more value is near 1). Then, you add that value to `lineCap`. You see the "ratio"/"percent" calculation? You have an offset, but I I'd tell you that the additional value to lineCap was from 0 to 100, then converted to -50 to 50 (just remove 50 to it), then divide it by 100 and you get -0.5 to 0.5. Do you see, or sense the logic that could you try?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a `UISlider` question, but rather a computation question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the mathematical function that describes your transform.
Assuming you don't really want the discrete steps, the following function should do the trick (this is untested):

```
@objc func stockSliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    let x = sender.value

    let offset = 0.7
    let computedSliderValue = abs(x - 0.5)

    stockChart.lineGap = offset - computedSliderValue
    stockChart.reDraw()
}
```

If you really want the steps, apply some rounding to `computedSliderValue`.